# How to use a component that has v-tippy in Storybook?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I am trying to create a storie using Storybook of a Vue 3 component that uses v-tippy but I keep getting erros.

The component that I import on the stories.js is this:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center" :class="[labelBellowStars ? 'flex-col justify-center': '']">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <IconBase
                v-tippy="{ content: 'Tooltip content', placement: 'bottom' }"
                :class="[star.active ? 'fill-yellow-500 hover:fill-yellow-300 dark:fill-yellow-300 dark:hover:fill-yellow-500' : 'fill-grayblue-10 dark:fill-grayblue-70', isEditable ? 'cursor-pointer' : '']"
                class="border-none focus:border-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-transparent"
                v-for="star in stars" :size="iconSize"
                @mouseleave="hoverStar(0)"
                @mouseover="hoverStar(star.id)"
                @click="selectStar(star.id)">
                <IconStar/>
            </IconBase>
        </div>
        <div>
            <small :class="[labelBellowStars ? 'ml-0': 'ml-4']" v-if="hasLabel">
                {{ label }}
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
import VueTippy from 'vue-tippy';
import './styles.sass';
import {
    IconBase,
    IconStar
} from '../../components/Icons';
/**
 *
 * @class StarsRating
 */
export default {
    name: "StarsRating",
    components: {IconStar, IconBase},
    directives: {
        Tippy: VueTippy.directive,
    },
```

Keeps showing this error because of the tooltip:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')
at withDirectives